# How to get cell index by clicking on GridView column in asp.net - simple method

Tags: asp.net, gridview, selectedindexchanged

I know this question have been asked many times and with my limited knowledge of JS I have tried everything, I simply can not make any solutions work. So I've bound my data to GridView :

```
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ID"))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("NAME"))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("CITY"))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("CURRENT JOB"))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("@COMPANY"))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("C")) ' communication
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("S")) 'select

            Dim ID As String
            Dim name As String
            Dim city As String
            Dim current_job As String
            Dim company As String
            Dim com As String

            For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                ID = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(1).ToString()
                name = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(2).ToString()
                city = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(3).ToString()
                current_job = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(9).ToString()
                company = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(10).ToString()

                If ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(12).ToString() = "" Then
                    com = ""
                Else
                    com = "X"
                End If

                dt.Rows.Add(ID, name, city, current_job, company, com, "S")

            Next

            candidate_grid_view.DataSource = dt
            candidate_grid_view.DataBind()
```

I've registered cell click on candidate_grid_view.OnRowDataBound event :

```
Protected Sub Candidate_OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(candidate_grid_view, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
        e.Row.Attributes("style") = "cursor:pointer"
    End If
End Sub
```

I can easy get row index by `candidate_grid_view.SelectedRow.RowIndex` in `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event, but I need click event for column (cell) that will register cell index (column index). There is no cellindex propery!?

```
Protected Sub Candidate_OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim index As Integer = candidate_grid_view.SelectedRow.RowIndex
End Sub
```

Why something that easy as getting column index in VB.NET so complicated in ASP.NET?

Comment: maybe you can tell us what you want to achieve? The reason the framework only has a default implementation for telling you which row is selected, is because it normally doesn't make any difference which cell within this row the user clicks. Maybe it is something different you need, like some buttons in your row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, havng a row click - very easy.

So, lets work our way though this.

first, a gv - simple markup like this:

```
    <div style="padding:25px;width:50%">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"  CssClass="table">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View" CssClass="btn"
                            OnClick="cmdView_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

Our code to fill is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)

        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader())
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub

Protected Sub cmdView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer

    Debug.Print("Row click index = " & gRow.RowIndex)

    ' get primary key (hidden by datakeys
    Dim PKID As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")
    Debug.Print("Data base row PKID = " & PKID)
    Debug.Print("hotel name of this row = " & gRow.Cells(2).Text)


End Sub
```

And now if we click on view button (for the row), then we have this:

[image]

Ok, so that so far - very easy.

Now, what about a row click anywhere - not necessary on the button?

Gee, all controls? I would dump "cells" and drop in standard asp.net controls into that GV - (such as I did for the button). However, with a lot of columns, this becomes a pain - (too many messy "templatefield" tags - I don't like those).

As a result, I would dump the GV, and go to a listview.

However, lets just force code our way though this. But, I been doing this for a long time - never had to just get the cell information.

But, you can say do this:

In our row data bound, just add a click event to each cell, say like this:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 2   ' skip last button cell
            Dim MyCell As TableCell = e.Row.Cells(i)
            Dim RowCol As string = e.Row.RowIndex & "," & i
            MyCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "MyClick('" & RowCol & "')")
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

All we did was add a row, and col value.

So, now in our markup, we have this:

```
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:HiddenField ID="HRowInfo" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdRowClick" runat="server" Text="Row click" ClientIDMode="Static"
            onclick="cmdRowClick_Click" CommandArgument="0" />
        <script>

            function MyClick(RowInfo) {

                $("#HRowInfo").val(RowInfo)
                $('#cmdRowClick').click()
            }
        </script>
```

So, we shove value into hidden field, and click our button - just a plane jane button below the grid (we would hide it with style="display:none"

And code behind is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdRowClick_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Debug.Print(HRowInfo.Value)

End Sub
```

Now, when I click on any cell, I get a output of the row, colum, say like this:

[image]

And from above, I can index into the Gridview.Rows and then cells the two values.

However, I am not convinced that we really need/want a click event on the cells - we "might", but then again, might be better to put some controls on that form - as a repating grid, and work on a row by row basis.

As noted, I tend to use ListView for this.

Say we have the above hotel list, but I want the user to enter a value in a "cell" for say the number of nights. But the grid displays the nightly rate, and when I enter the number of nights, I want another column to show the total cost.

We COULD try and deal and wire up say a cell, but is is VERY rare i need to do this.

But, with a standard control, it does become somewhat easy.

As I stated, I never really liked GV for doing this kind of thing, but lets add to above the nights text box, the night rate, and a total column.

(We ARE better to use a listview, but no big deal).

so, lets assume this markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"  CssClass="table">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nights">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNights" runat="server" TextMode="Number"
                            Text = '<%# Eval("Nights") %>'  Width ="40">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Per night">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price", "{0:C2}") %>' >
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtAmount" runat="server"
                            Text='<%# Eval("Tamount", "{0:c}") %>'
                            width="50"
                            >
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
```

So, same code to fill - (no row data bound event).

Ok, so we now have this:

[image]

Now, lets assume I want to change the number of nights. I don't REALLY need a cell click, do I? I just want the user to type in the number of nights, and then say update the Total amount.

So, we just add a plane jane text changed event to that text box, (and auto post-back).

So, the markup becomes this:

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nights">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNights" runat="server" TextMode="Number"
                            Text = '<%# Eval("Nights") %>'  Width ="40"
                            OnTextChanged="txtNights_TextChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="true"
                            >
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

We now can just click on any "nights" cell in the grid, enter a new value and hit tab, or move out and click on another row.

the code for the text changed event looks like this:

```
Protected Sub txtNights_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim txtNights As TextBox = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = txtNights.NamingContainer

    Dim lPrice As Label = gRow.FindControl("LPrice")
    Dim TotalAmount As Label = gRow.FindControl("txtAmount")

    TotalAmount.Text = (lPrice.Text * txtNights.Text).ToString("C2")


End Sub
```

So, this is why I am suggesting that you in general don't needd a cell click event.

You "might", but in most cases I don't think you do.